# Why is lumen/laravel throwing error "Too few arguments passed" when using find/findmany?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I have an array of ids I want to use to get matching records from a table. 
Code looks like this:

```
$res = Extensiontables_Registry::findmany($ids[0])->get();
```

The full context looks like this:

```
  public function getData(Request $request){
    $ad_groupsOfUser = $this->getRoles($request);
    $ids = $ad_groupsOfUser->pluck('id');

    $res = Extensiontables_Registry::findmany($ids[0])->get();

    return response()->json($res, 200);
  }

  public function getRoles(Request $request)
  {
    $ad_groups = Ad_user::find($request->decodedToken->user_id)->ad_groups()->get();

    //return response()->json($roles, 200);
    return $ad_groups;
  }
```

$ids definitely is an array and contains values, I've debugged it. 
But why isn't it working with find/findmany?
This is the full error I get:

```
 (1/1) ArgumentCountError

Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in E:\aether-backend\app\Http\Controllers\UserController.php on line 49 and at least 1 expected
```

Comment: You don't need to use `get` after `find`. Find already fetches 1 result from database and get fetches a collection of results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you use find it fetches the data for you. get() is used after a where clause

```
Model::find();

Model::where(['key' , 1])->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `whereIn()` method: check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses)

```
$res = Extensiontables_Registry::whereIn('id',$ids)->get(); //$ids = [1,2,3,...]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use find in place of findMany.

Since you trying to fetch one data. Good approach is to use whereIn method.

```
public function getData(Request $request){
    $adGroupsOfUser = $this->getRoles($request);
    $ids = $adGroupsOfUser->pluck('id');

    $response = Extensiontables_Registry::whereIn($ids->toArray())->get();

    return response()->json($response, 200);
  }
```